# Bootstrap 3.3+ carousel not compatible with older code?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

i wanted to use this carousel: http://www.bootply.com/94452
but when I implement it to my site (using Bootstrap 3.3.4) the animation is moving the whole carousel instead of sliding just one "frame". When I switch to 3.2.0 css its working properly.
I have found this partial solution:

```
/*
WHAT IS NEW IN 3.3: "Added transforms to improve carousel performance in modern browsers."
now override the 3.3 new styles for modern browsers & apply opacity
*/
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
          -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
          -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); 
    }
    .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
    .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active {
          -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);  
    }
}
```

but it removes the animation completely. Does anyone has any idea how to make it work under Bootstrap 3.3+?
Thanks!

Comment: I have just found out that the workaround acts really weird in Firefox...